# Hibernate. Foreign key mapping by id

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, foreign-keys

I want to create @ManyToOne mapping between Acount and Record. One account can have a lot of records. But i don't want to add Account field in Record class or vice versa. Could you please help me to describe this in annotations?

```
@Entity
public class Account {

  @Id
  ... getId();
}

@Entity
public class Record {

  @Id
  ... getId();

  @?????
  ... getAccountId();

}
```

Comment: If you don't want to add an actual Account or Record field, then what's the point of the mapping? If all you want to get back is an ID, then you don't need any sort of mapping. Just put the `accountId` or `recordId` in as a regular column.

Comment: What about foreign keys?

Comment: Could you clarify that? The `accountId` or `recordId` _is_ the foreign key.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like you're using Hibernate to generate your schema. Do you want to use a join table? What is the point of putting the account/record ID in the entity but not a proper account/record field?

Comment: @Andrew: Do the columns even exist in the database? You are not sharing all the relevant information here. Just because the foreign key constraint doesn't actually exist (given that the columsn for them DO exist), you can still map it like so in Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, I am using hibernate to generate schema. I want to generate SQL code like this : create table Account(id...); create table Record(id, acc_id. foreign key...); Why I don't want to do it in the True Hibernate Way it is a long story) It doesn't matter now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping entities to tables is the way Hibernate usually works, if you don't want the Account class in Record you can simply define accountId as long (or int, whichever is ok) and not annotate it unless you need a different column name.
But I would suggest not to do it.

Comment: In this case hibernate will not create foreign key automatically. This is a problem.

Comment: I guess there is no way to do it like you want then; in Hibernate to define a foreign key you need a target entity

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the foreign key constraints to either table, you can create a separate table with the constraints that allows you to make the relation.

```
accountId | recordId
--------------------
 1        | 2
 1        | 3
 2        | 4
```

With JPA...

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(table=TABLE_NAME_ABOVE,name="accountId")
public Account getAccount(){ ... }
```

Comment: I want this foreign key. Relations via separate table... Seems like poor design.