# hibernate: How to map a variable as foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

is it possible to declare a variable `Long documentID` as Foreign key instead of the natural `Document document`?Below the example:

```
@Entity
@Table("document")
class Document{
   ...
   @Id
   Long id;
   ...
}

@Entity
@Table("something")
class Something{
   ....
   //instead of
   @ManyToOne
   Document document;

   // this one with the appropriate annotations
   Long documentID;
   ...
}
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The purpose of using on ORM is to translate the logical representation of objects in to a relational form that is capable of being stored in the database. If you want to handle foreign keys directly, why use an ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: I'd like to do that because I can't modify Document class so I can't map as bidirectional-mappings wich is the Hibernate preferred way! Another issue is the performance...i need to improve the perfomences of other methods not written here...

Comment: btw, I will solve my problem using a different strategy not concerning hibernate...thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

It seems a similar question have already appeared: [Hibernate. Foreign key mapping by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487055/hibernate-foreign-key-mapping-by-id)

It is not recommended to work with hibernate in such manner.